# Second search box takes too long time to display result, sometimes browser crashed

Tags: jquery, performance, laravel-5.3

I have a dropdown list - country, generated by jquery and upon selection it will load all cities under the selected country into another UL. I have added a search function for the second UL; whenever I type in any alphabet it takes long time to respond and some times lead to browser crash. How can I handle it.

For those country with minimum amount of cities the second search function works perfectly fine, just that when come to huge country like china, us, uk etc, the search/filter function will lead to crash.

need advice on how to make the search / filter function properly.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      origin_dropdown();
    }

    function myFunction(e) {
      name = e;
      $("." + e + "_dropdown").toggle();
      //document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    }

    function filterFunction(e) {
      var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
      name = e;
      input = $(".input_" + e).val();
      filter = input.toUpperCase();
      a = $("." + e + "_dropdown").find("li");

      for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i].innerText.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          $(a[i]).show();
        } else {
          $(a[i]).hide();
        }
      }
    }

    function filterFunction_cities(e) {
      var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
      name = e;
      input = $(".input_" + e).val();
      filter = input.toUpperCase();
      a = $("#origin_cities_list").find("li");

      for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i].innerText.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          $(a[i]).show();
        } else {
          $(a[i]).hide();
        }
      }
    }

    function origin_dropdown() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/advance/origin",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
          $(data.result).each(function(key, value) {
            name = value.country_name.replace(/ /g, "_");
            //cities = value.full_name_nd.replace(/ /g,"_");
            list = $("<li>").addClass(name).text(value.country_name);
            cbox = $("<input>").addClass(name).attr("type", "checkbox").val(value.country_name).click(function() {
              selected_cBox = $(this).val();
              new_div = $("<div>").addClass("selected_origin").text(selected_cBox);
              $('.selected_container').append(new_div);

              var tmp = {
                'country': []
              };
              tmp['country'].push(selected_cBox);
              console.log(tmp);
              // to get cities within the selected country and append to list
              $.ajax({
                url: "/advance/origin_cities",
                type: 'POST',
                data: tmp,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                  $(data.result).each(function(key, value) {
                    city_name = value.full_name_nd.replace(/ /g, "_");
                    country_name = value.country_name.replace(/ /g, "_");
                    list = $("<li>").addClass(value.country_name, city_name).text(value.full_name_nd);
                    cbox = $("<input>").addClass(value.country_name, city_name).attr("type", "checkbox").val(value.full_name_nd).click(function() {
                      selected_cBox = $(this).val();
                      new_div = $("<div>").addClass("selected_origin").text(selected_cBox);
                      $('.selected_container').append(new_div);
                    })
                    combine = list.prepend(cbox);
                    $('#origin_cities_list').append(combine);
                  })
                }
              })
            });
            combine = list.prepend(cbox);
            $('#origin_list').append(combine);
          })
        }
      });
    }
```

```html
<div id="myModal_origin" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <div class="dropdown_origin">
      <button onclick="myFunction('origin')" class="dropbtn">Country of Origin</button>
      <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content origin_dropdown">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" class="input_origin" onkeyup="filterFunction('Origin')">
        <ul id="origin_list" class="dynamic_list">
        </ul>
        <ul id="origin_cities_list" class="dynamic_list">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" class="input_cities" onkeyup="filterFunction_cities('Cities')">
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

i have refined my JQuery and trying to resolve out the issue as i found the previous code keep calling ajax for cities.

below are my new code but im still getting the same issue

```
function origin_dropdown(){
$.ajax({
    url:"/advance/origin",
    type:'POST',
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(data){
        $(data.result).each(function(key,value){ 
            name = value.country_name.replace(/ /g,"_");
            //cities = value.full_name_nd.replace(/ /g,"_");
            list = $("<li>").addClass(name).text(value.country_name);
            cbox = $("<input>").addClass(name).addClass("_country").attr("type","checkbox").val(value.country_name);
            combine = list.prepend(cbox);
            $('#origin_list').append(combine);
        }); 
    }
})
}

function Origin_cities_dropdown(ctry){

$(".origin_dropdown").toggle();
var tmp = {'country':[]};
tmp['country'].push(ctry);
console.log(tmp);

$.ajax({
    url:"/advance/origin_cities",
    type:'POST',
    data:tmp,
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(data){
        console.log("success");
        $(data.result).each(function(key,value){        
            city_name = value.full_name_nd.replace(/ /g,"_");
            country_name = value.country_name.replace(/ /g,"_");
            list = $("<li>").addClass(value.country_name, city_name).text(value.full_name_nd);
            cbox = $("<input>").addClass(value.country_name, city_name).attr("type","checkbox").val(value.full_name_nd).click(function(){
                selected_cBox = $(this).val();
                new_div = $("<div>").addClass("selected_origin").text(selected_cBox);
                $('.selected_container').append(new_div);
            })
            combine = list.prepend(cbox);
            $('#origin_cities_list').append(combine);
        })
    }
})
}

<!--Location Selection Modal-->
        <div id="myModal_origin" class="modal">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="row modal-content">
                        <span class="close">&times;</span>
                            <div class="dropdown_origin  col-sm-12 col-md-12 centered">
                                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 centered"><p>Country of Origin</p></div>
                                <input onclick="myFunction('origin')" class="dropbtn" readonly></input>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" class="input_origin" onkeyup="filterFunction('Origin')" style="display: none;">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" class="input_cities" onkeyup="filterFunction_cities('Cities')" style="display: none;">
                                <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content origin_dropdown col-sm-12 col-md-12 centered">                        
                                    <ul id="origin_list" class="dynamic_list">
                                    </ul>
                                </div>        
                                <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content cities_dropdown col-sm-12 col-md-12 centered">        
                                    <ul id="origin_cities_list" class="dynamic_list">

                                    </ul> 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

$(document).ready(function() {
  origin_dropdown();
}
```

Comment: Your code has syntax errors. Please correct it. - this is not valid: `$(document).ready(function() {
      origin_dropdown();
    }`

Comment: I suggest you create a concatenated html string and inject that instead of creating new objects and append them

Comment: @mplungjan, sorry i am not understand as what is concatenated html string, and the script can be run properly without any error, just that the filter function will crashed the browser.

Answer (score 0):

This is faster for large numbers

```js
$("##origin_cities_list").on("click","[type=checkbox]",function() {
  var new_div = $("<div>").addClass("selected_origin").text(this.value);
  $('.selected_container').append(new_div);
});
```

using

```
success: function(data) {
  var html = [];
  $(data.result).each(function(key, value) {
    city_name = value.full_name_nd.replace(/ /g, "_");
    country_name = value.country_name.replace(/ /g, "_");
    html.push('<li class="'+value.country_name +" " + city_name+">'+value.full_name_nd+'<input class="'+value.country_name +" "+ city_name +' type="checkbox" value="'+value.full_name_nd+'"/>');
  })
  $("#origin_cities_list").append(html.join(''));
}
```